# Vue.js - Axios Get request returned [object Object]

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

My project is a Vue.js project. I used Flask for api. When i try axios.get request, my api returned objec Objet. Actually when i try same request in Postman, it's work. It returns data.

My code is here:

```
<script>

   import axios from 'axios'

   const URL = 'http://localhost:8080/'

   mounted(){

   axios.get(URL + "/KPI/get_category/1").then(response=>{
   for (const data in response.data) {
              this.kalite.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data[data])))
    }  

    for(const data in this.kalite){

      axios.get(URL + "/KPI/get_last_input/"+this.kalite[data] 
      ['id']).then(response=>{
                
                 console.log("response " + response)
    
       })
    }
})
 }
 </script>
```

I see in console like this:
response [object Object]

Comment: You're coercing the object to a string by concatenating it with "response " - if you don't want to just see [object Object], maybe _don't do that_.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: Same output : object Object

Comment: Try without string "response"

Comment: Ups.. Thank you. It's work

Answer (score 0):

With Axios you should be able to get JSON by `reponse.data`.

If using fetch, `await response.json()` should do the trick.

You should get familiar with the [Network-tab in Devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/), here you can inspect the response, and get an understanding of the data. Specifically [Inspect a resource's details](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#details)